# After protein shakes and BCAA, what is the next supplement to take?

Tags: supplements

I've recently started taking BCAA to help me recuperate after a gym session as it was taking me a long time to recuperate.  Now recuperation is almost instant.

I'm trying to gain muscle mass, which is working fairly well.  But wanted to know what would be the next supplement to take.

I'm already taking my daily protein shake (39 grams of protein), multi-vitamin, Omega-3 and now BCAA.  I'm only taking 2 doses of the BCAA and the instructions says I can take up to three a day.

Any suggestions or great articles would be great.  I already read a lot, but all everyone offers is an opinion, but no real general guideline.

I should also note that I also take Siberian Ginseng.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creatine and L-Glutamine seem like good choices. L-Glutamine may already be included in your BCAA mix. Both are good for recovery and growth; creatine also provides extra easily-accessible fuel to your muscles during a lift so that you can get that extra rep cranked out.

<s>Do avoid taking creatine and L-Glutamine at the same time, as they can compete for receptors to be absorbed in the body. I tend to take L-Glutamine about an hour before working out and creatine immediately afterward. (Also creatine first thing in the morning, and L-Glutamine last thing at night before bed)</s>

Update: per [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/910/22), it seems that there may not, in fact, be competition between these two supplements, so they could be taken together.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Greg, but creatine is going to add a lot of water weight. Do your research on which creatine to take. Monohydrate is the most common but there are some others types.

If you're looking for performance then creatine and some type of Nitric Oxide Booster such as Nitrix or NoXplode or just a crap load of L-Arginine.

I use Nitrix and I like it, but a good creatine blend can go a long way for your pumps and recovery.

Comment: This is good stuff too.  Thanks.  Looking to try out your suggestion as well.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest that you replace those BCAA doses with your Whey shake. If you aren't using whey isolate, switch to that one. The only difference between those two is, BCAA's are taken instantly while isolate might take 30-60 mins to become absorbed.

generally, a 90-95% protein rate whey isolate contains 5-8 grams of BCAA and costs around the 1/4th of the price.

If it doesn't imbalance your caloric intake, I would spend the money on the whey. but if additional 3 scoops of whey extra in your current diet to replace BCAA might hinder your diet (that is an additional 300-400kcal compared to 50kcals of BCAAs you are taking as far as I can guess), then stick to it. There is no harm in it.

If you wanna add something new to your supplements I would advice adding the following to your pre-workout supplementation:

200mg caffeine (3 cups of strong coffee an hour before training)
Beta-Alanine (2-5g) in case you don't like the tingling sensation or you use beta-blockers for anti-immunogens by any chance, it is a well advised supplement for your pre-workout and allround health.
Arginine alpha-ketoglutarate (AKG) is a nice synthesis and Nitric balancer for during your workouts which helps a lot in general.
Citrulline Mallate - I would take this if you can afford this instead of AKG, but it is costly.

More than that, I would advice not to take any supplementation except good coffee whey and creatine monohydrate in micronized creapure brand. You can do 95% as good as with those. Those pre- and pos- workout supplement blends are only for those who build muscle for work, extreme hobby or obsession of as a pure goal. If you are doing it for fun and the looks, it is not even necessary to use BCAAs.

Comment: Please refrain from unnecessarily advising people to comment below, it is a core feature of StackExchange and people are aware of it. Emoticons are frowned upon on the network, too.

Comment: Thanks @Baarn. I beleive you just made me quit this stack. Congratulations :)

Comment: I apologize if I was a bit rude. On StackExchange answers should not contain any [salutations, greetings, signatures](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/176874) or similar features. This extends to [emoticons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137570/176874).